# Regex for slash followed by any number

Tags: regex

What would be the correct way of writing a regex that states:

`/` followed by any number

For example, gets fired with "/1", "/2", but not "/a" etc.

Comment: what have your tried? And what language?

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/ is a great place to start learning regular expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PCRE

```
/\/\d/
```

this will match any '/' followed by any single character number number.

```
/\/\d+/
```

this will match '/' followed by any set of consecutive numbers.

```
/^\/d+$/
```

this will match '/' followed by any set of consecutive numbers that are the only thing on that line.

Comment: What are the slashes at the beginning and end for?

Comment: They are delimiters for Perl Compatible Regular Expressions (PCRE). Here is a php article about them (php uses PCRE). http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php

Comment: Thanks! And apologies for a vague question, but this is what I was looking for.